# How do I populate the index number of a option value list with cheerio?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

hi guys i am trying to get the index number of a list from a website using cheerio. for example the index number for "40 - only one left" is 2.

how would i go about getting the number 2 by having only '40' to match (without only one left)?

```
<option value="">Select Size</option>
<option value="2970"> 40 - only one left</option>
<option value="2973"> 41 - only one left</option>
<option value="2976"> 42 - only one left</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first select the `<option>` by text using the cheerio/jQuery selector `:contains` (the text could be anything), then call the function `index` to get its index inside its parent:

```
var index = $("option:contains('40')").index();
```

**Note:** The function `index` returns a 0-indexed result that starts from 0, if you want 1-indexed result, then simply add 1 to it.

**Demo (using jQuery, which cheerio is based on):**

```js
var index = $("option:contains('40')").index();

console.log(index);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="">Select Size</option>
  <option value="2970"> 40 - only one left</option>
  <option value="2973"> 41 - only one left</option>
  <option value="2976"> 42 - only one left</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
function getindex(searchValue) {
    // you probably want to have a class for them OR pass an array of options 
    // to this function, because your html might have options in other places
    const inner = document.body.getElementsByTagName('option');
    for (let i = 0; i < inner.length; i++) {
        if (inner[i].innerHTML.includes(searchValue)) return i;
    }
    return 'no match'

}
 // remember that indexing starts at 0,
 // thus option 'Select Size' - is the first one with the index 0
 // and `40` - is the index 1
getindex('40'); // returns index 1
```